# Confused about whether or not I should use Bayes' Theorem?

Tags: probability

There are 10 students preparing for a TV show audition. Eight of them can sing while five
of them can dance. All selections are made without replacement

Two students are randomly selected. What is the chance that the first student can only sing given that the second student can dance?

I'm not quite sure whether I should use the normal conditional probability or I should use Bayes' Theorem here.

Can I interpret that since the wording of the question mentions that the first student can only sing given that the second student can dance had already happened. So that the probability calculation would be :

P(First Student can only sing | Second Student can dance)=P(First|Second) = $\frac{P(First \cap Second)}{P(Second)}$ =
$\frac{(\frac{5}{10} \cdot\ \frac{5}{9} )}{(\frac{5}{9})}$ = $\frac{5}{10}$

What are some tips on how to know when to apply normal conditional probability formula and when to apply Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: Your probability calculation is incorrect. You are treating the events as independent, but they are not.

Comment: Hint: the order of the two selected students is irrelevant so the probability is not affected if you switch the words "first" and "second".

Comment: Is it so that every student can sing or dance? It is essential information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is permitted to switch the words "first" and "second" because the order of the students is irrelevant.

So it is enough to find: $$P(\text{second can only sing}\mid\text{first can dance})$$

Assuming that every student can sing or dance there are $5$ students that can only sing.

If the first can dance then it is for sure that the first is not a student that can only sing.

So the second is chosen from $9$ students of which exactly $5$ can only sing.

That gives:

$$P(\text{second can only sing}\mid\text{first can dance})=\frac59$$

---

**edit**

Bayes rule is not needed here but can be applied. If $S_1$ denotes the event that the first student can only sing and $D_2$ denotes the event that the second student can dance then:$$P\left(S_{1}\mid D_{2}\right)=\frac{P\left(D_{2}\mid S_{1}\right)P\left(S_{1}\right)}{P\left(D_{2}\mid S_{1}\right)P\left(S_{1}\right)+P\left(D_{2}\mid S_{1}^{\complement}\right)P\left(S_{1}^{\complement}\right)}=\frac{\frac{5}{9}\frac{5}{10}}{\frac{5}{9}\frac{5}{10}+\frac{4}{9}\frac{5}{10}}=\frac59$$

Comment: I like your way of intuitively solving this problem. but if we were to do it by formula, is bayes' theorem needed here?

Comment: @pino231 Right now I do not have the opportunity to think about it.  Later I will take a second look. This also because I see that the answer of Zoli is not the same.

Comment: Bayes rule can be used, but it only makes things more complicated. See my edit.

Comment: thank you for the explanation !

Answer (score 1):

How many possibilities are there to distribute $5$ dancer "titles" and $8$ singer "title" among $10$ students. As shown below, there ore ${10 \choose 5} $ dancer selections and there are ${10\choose 8}$ singer selections.
[image]

The total is $${10\choose 8}{10 \choose 5} $$
because the two selections are independent.

The next question: How many possibilities are there to such that the first member is a singe $S$ the second is an $S$ or an $SD$?

As the figure below shows

[image]

the total number of possibilities is

$${8\choose 6}{8\choose 4}+{8 \choose 7}{8\choose 4}.$$

That is, the probability that the first student can only sing and the second student can dance is

$$\frac{{8\choose 6}{8\choose 4}+{8 \choose 7}{8\choose 4}}{{10\choose 8}{10 \choose 5} }=\frac29.$$

In order to calculate the conditional probability, we will have to divide the above probability by the probability that a student can dance, which probability is $\frac12.$

The final result is then $$\frac 49.$$

**An edit / another result**

As drhab suggested, it my be wrong to assume that there are participants who can neither dance nor sing. In this case the total number of possibilities is

$${10\choose 8}{8 \choose 3}={10\choose 5}{5\choose 3}=2520.$$
This is because if we give the title of "singer" to $8$ participants then $2$ of the $10$ remain untalented. So when distributing the "dancer" titles we have to donate $2$ of them to the yet untalented participants and the rest will got to the $8 $ singers. (And the other way around.)

Based on the same logic, the number of possibilities when we have two singers selected or two singers and a dancer selected

$${8\choose 6}{6\choose 3}+{8\choose 6}{6\choose 2}=980$$

The conditional probability we seek is then

$$\frac{\frac{{8\choose 6}{6\choose 3}+{8\choose 6}{6\choose 2}}{{10\choose 8}{8 \choose 3}}}{\frac12}=\frac79.$$

I did not get drhab's solution. Where is the mistake?

Comment: This is a very interesting way of thinking about this problem

Comment: Your setup does not exclude that there are students that cannot dance and cannot sing as well.

Comment: @drhab: Do you mean that considering the first two students, it is not excluded that neither of them can dance or sing?

Comment: I mean that independent distribution of titels dancer and singer also includes the possibilities where students are no singer *and* no dancer. I am not saying that it is wrong though and already asked the OP for clarification. It is is probably the cause of the fact that we have different answers.

Comment: Ah, I get you. But I took it for granted that that there may be no singer-dancers... At least, I understand your answer now.

Comment: @drhab: I tried to do it your way (assuming that nobody remain untalented) but I did not get the same answer. Where might be (my?) mistake?

Comment: Sorry, but a I have to postpone a second look.

Comment: I think it is wrong to divide by $\frac12$. If $D$ stands for "dancer", $S$ for "singer" and $B$ for "both" then there are $\frac{9!}{5!3!1!}+\frac{9!}{5!2!2!}$ rows with on the second spot a $D$ or a $B$. Further  $\frac{8!}{4!3!1!}+\frac{8!}{4!2!2!}$ of these rows have on the first spot an $S$. The conditional probability is found by dividing and gives $\frac59$.